# Powerpoint VBA Comments

Tags: vba, powerpoint

When creating comments via VBA or c# directly with the COM object comments always result in the following error "Comments (unknown member) : Illegal value."

I have used the default code provided by Microsoft's team ([text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.comments):

```
Sub AddComment()

    Dim sldNew As Slide
    Dim cmtNew As Comment

    Set sldNew = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(Index:=1, _
        Layout:=ppLayoutBlank)

    Set cmtNew = sldNew.Comments.Add(Left:=12, Top:=12, _
        Author:="Jeff Smith", AuthorInitials:="JS", _
        Text:="You might consider reviewing the new specs" & _
        "for more up-to-date information.")

End Sub
```

And not that this fails and calls the same error referenced above. Note I have done extensive research and not sure if this is due to the new Modern Comments or what is causing the issue.

Also, I have tried the same via the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Powerpoint.Comments` (within a COM addin) and the same isssue persists which lead me to try via VBA and note that it appears the issue is on the Application side.

```
// ignore implementation of Application.PowerPoint.Utilities.ActiveSlide -> I have confirmed its not null and returns the active slide
var slide = Application.PowerPoint.Utilities.ActiveSlide;

slide.Comments.Add(12, 12, "Jeff Smith", "JS", "You might consider reviewing the new specs for more up-to-date information.");
```

Tried creating a basic comment via the Microsoft's how-to but no comments are created

Comment: It actually seems that the `Add2` method should be used --> a link in the blue highlighted section [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.comments.add) sends [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.comments.add2), yet I could not find a way to make it work,. I tried [this](http://skp.mvps.org/2013/update-comments.htm) and it did not work. I could not find any working sample that explains how to enter the `ProviderID` nor the `UserID`

Comment: I tried adding a comment manually , from which I could gather, through `Debug.Print`,  `Author`, `AuthorInitials`, `Provider ID` and `User ID`, yet there was no way I could have it work by using this items of information.

Comment: In my case the error seems to be in the initials, that I have empty. Is it your case, too? I [found](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.userinitials) how to set them, but only for Word.

Comment: @OranG.Utan yes I do see there is a new Add2, which is designed for Modern Comments, that requires UserID and ProviderID, which are obtained from Microsoft and help with trackign and implementation of Modern Comments. However, as you commented even manually they do not work. Regardless if `initials` are inputted or null `Comments.Add()` fails. It appears this is completely broken in the VBA / COM Interop object model.

Comment: I re-read the question, and you mean that you have tried what is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-12/ff762972(v=office.12)) already? It would be very useful to automate comments insertion.

Comment: This would be yet [another case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64276775/18247317) in which it is not possible to access all functionalities listed in the ribbon also  see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75182497/18247317). I have been struggling with what I linked for the past months and I cannot figure out how to.

Comment: @OranG.Utan I took a look at the two links - however, these do not appear to be very material to this thread. Which is that the `Comments.Add()` and `Comments.Add2()` is currently broken both in VBA and COM Interop. Also, its logical that if it doesnt work in COM it wont work in VBA or vice versa. However, Microsoft does not have any direct feedback since there is no open repository on Github and their documentation only suggests posts to Stackoverflow with `vba` tags. Unclear if these are monitored by them. I'm guessing no.

Comment: No, they are not, I reported as samples of actions accessible from the ribbon but not  through VBA.